# Python: Create new column and row base on different column in CSV file

Tags: python, database, pandas, csv, time

I have a large data set and i want to create new column and row base on column `starttime` and `endtime`. Example: `starttime = 5`, `endtime = 7`. I want a new column named `Hour` with a value of `[5,7)`.

My data:

```
Id      name    starttime   endtime
1000    a       5           7
1001    b       13          16
1002    c       23          2
```

The result i want:

```
id      name    hour
1000    a       5
1000    a       6
1001    b       13
1001    b       14
1001    b       15
1002    c       23
1002    c       24
1002    c       1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating over the dataframe can solve it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1000, 'a', 5, 7], [1001, 'b', 13, 16], [1002, 'c', 23, 2]],
                  columns=['Id', 'name', 'starttime', 'endtime'])

new_columns = ['id', 'name', 'hour']
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=new_columns)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    start = int(row['starttime'])
    end = int(row['endtime'])
    if end > start:
        for counter in range(start, end):
            new_df = new_df.append(pd.DataFrame([[int(row['Id']), row['name'], int(counter)]],
                                                columns=new_columns),
                                   ignore_index=True)
    else:
        for counter in range(start, 25):
            new_df = new_df.append(pd.DataFrame([[int(row['Id']), row['name'], int(counter)]],
                                                columns=new_columns),
                                   ignore_index=True)
        for counter in range(1, end):
            new_df = new_df.append(pd.DataFrame([[int(row['Id']), row['name'], int(counter)]],
                                                columns=new_columns),
                                   ignore_index=True)
```